# Графический интерфейс в C++ и построение графиков

Tags: c++

Условие задачи: тело летит под углом к горизонту, надо нарисовать график и сделать графический интерфейс.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoOutputCP(1251);

    //константа -ускорение свободного падения и число pi;
    const double g=9.8;
    const double pi=3.14;

    //sag diskretnosti po vremeni;
    double dt=0.0001;

    //rabochii peremennii;
    double v,alipha,T,t,u,x=0,y=0;
    int n=0;

    //ввод параметров задачи;
    cout<<"введите начальную скорость v = ";
    cin>>v;
    cout<<"введите угол alipha = " ;
    cin>>alipha;

    //перевод градусов в радианы;
    alipha=alipha*pi/180;
    T=2*v*sin(alipha)/g;
    cout<<"введите время t < " <<T<< " ; " ;
    cin>>t ;

    //начальная скорость(проекция);
    x=v*t*cos(alipha);
    y=v*t*cos(alipha)-g*t*t/2;

    //вычислим координаты тела;
    do{
        n++;
        y+=u*dt;
        x+=v*dt;
        u-=g*dt;
    }while((y>0)&&(n*dt<t));

    //вывод результатовс учетом конечного времени полёта;
    cout<<"y = " <<y<< " : ";
    cout<<(t<sqrt(2*v*sin(alipha)/g)?v*sin(alipha)*t-g*t*t/2:0)<<endl;
    cout<<"x = " <<x<< " : ";
    cout<<(t<sqrt(2*v*sin(alipha)/g)?v*cos(alipha)*t:v*v*sin(2*alipha)/g)<<endl;

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}

{
    //чертим график;
    while(T<0.001);
    {
        T=T-0.001;
        canvas->moveto (start x ; start y);
        x=v*t*cos(alipha);
        y=v*t*cos(alipha)-g*t*t/2;
        canvas->lineto (x;y);
    }
    if T<0.001 ;
    {
        T=0;
        canvas->moveto (start x ; start y);
        x=0;
        y=0;
        canvas->lineto (x;y);
    }

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

Вот что получилось, как можно дополнить?

Comment: не думаю что это еще можно чем-то дополнить )))

Comment: ну изв что сплошной текст

Comment: поправить, там есть специальный теги

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Плохо понятна фраза: "как можно дополнить". Приведенный вами код, не является рабочим.

1. Блок кода после функции main не ялвяется функцией.
2. Переменная canvas нигде не обяъвлена и что это неизвестно.

Собственно необходимо взять расчетные данные и отобразить график на их основе.